# Styled-components with npm link results in the error: "Trying to insert a new style tag, but the given Node is unmounted"

Tags: reactjs, npm, styled-components, npm-link

I have created my own npm package (created with nwb) where I use styled-components. In my consuming app, I'm also using styled-components.

The problem is. *Everything works fine when installing my npm package via* `npm install`. However, when using `npm link` the following error message occurs when entering to some other react-router route:

```
Error: Trying to insert a new style tag, but the given Node is unmounted!

* Are you using a custom target that isn't mounted?
* Does your document not have a valid head element?
* Have you accidentally removed a style tag manually?
```

In my npm package I have set the styled-components as peer dependency and as devDependency as follows:

```
...
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": "16.x",
  "styled-components": "^3.4.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
  "nwb": "0.23.x",
  "react": "^16.4.2",
  "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
  "styled-components": "^3.4.4"
},
...
```

Why styled-components fails to work when using `npm link`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is happening because you have two instances of `styled-components` installed.

Therefore removing `styled-components` as a devDependency in `package.json` and try using `$ npm link` or if you use npm > 5.1.0 try using `npm link --only=production` which would exclude dev dependencies installation.

Note: Please delete `node_modules` before running `$ npm link`

Comment: Thanks for reply. Indeed removing styled-components from devDepencies fixes the npm link issue. However, if it's only left in peerDependencies then I cannot run my package anymore standalone thus cannot test it.

Comment: @RootNode for which I have suggested another solution use npm link --only=production

Comment: I tried it, unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem, it ends up the same error. I guess that is supposed to be used in the module app, not in the consuming app.

Comment: @RootNode what npm version are you on ? It will work only if version is above 5.1.0  https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17631 check this once

Comment: I'm using 6.4.1

Comment: Finally got it working. But instead of just using `npm link --only=production` *you should first remove `node_modules` from your module*. And then say `npm link --only=production`. If you want to edit your answer so that it says something like: "first remove `node_modules` and then say `npm link --only=production`". I can then accept it. Thank you.